# Joining 2 different node if they have same class Id firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the structure i want after saving Qr  [QRdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaB6b.png)

This is the attendance after scanning"recordAttendance" [recordAttendance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQaRx.png)
I want them to join together

This is my desired json structure for combining "QRdata" with "recordAttendance" [CombineQRdata and recordAttendance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm8hV.png)

Help me combining it.

This is what i have tried. When i click save qr button, it will perform saveImage and i want to save under QRdata a list of student with same class id.

```
void saveImage() {
    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File directory = new File(path + "/folder/subfolder");
        directory.mkdirs();

        String filename = "image.jpg";
        File file = new File(directory, filename);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), filename, filename);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Saved in  " + file, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String selectedTerm = term.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String selectedCourse = courses.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String enteredClassId = classid.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

        if (selectedCourse.isEmpty() || enteredClassId.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Course ID and Class ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        String profUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DatabaseReference qrDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("QRdata");
        String qrData = getQRCodeData(selectedCourse, enteredClassId, selectedTerm); // Retrieve QR code data

        qrDataRef.child(profUid)
                .child(selectedCourse)
                .child(enteredClassId)
                .child(selectedTerm)
                .child(getCurrentDate())
                .setValue(qrData)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // QR code data saved successfully
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "QR code data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Failed to save QR code data
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to save QR code data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getQRCodeData(String selectedCourse, String enteredClassId, String selectedTerm) {
    if (enrollSubData != null) {
        Map<String, Object> courseData = (Map<String, Object>) enrollSubData.get(selectedCourse);
        if (courseData != null) {
            Map<String, Object> classData = (Map<String, Object>) courseData.get(enteredClassId);
            if (classData != null) {
                Object qrDataObj = classData.get(selectedTerm);
                if (qrDataObj != null) {
                    return qrDataObj.toString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ""; // Return empty string if QR code data is not found
}
```

Comment: Can you please highlight what is the exact data you want to get? Please also show us what you have tried and what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: i want to get prof uid> subject> classId>term>date>list of students

Comment: but its not giving me list of students

Comment: Have you trued to use hard-coded values in your reference? Does it work that way?

Comment: yes, it save but when i dynamically want to call list of student, it gives me error

Comment: "it gives me error" What error? Please edit your question to include the exact, complete error message - and (if available) the stack trace.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.